# How can i restrict login to a certain places only? I don't want my users to be login everywhere but the location I choose

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

Better block mobile data connection first. Before communicate to ur server check device connected IP & Ur wifi address same. If its true, continue to serve data. Make sure device connect via only wifi.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You need to know the ip address of the wifi or the wifi's unique address. there are several packages that can help with that in flutter. For university location, I suggest finding out the precise longitude and latitude location of your university. Then use the student's mobile phone to determine and compare longitude and latitude. There are also flutter packages for getting long & lat.